# Deleted protected content cannot be downloaded again in the same session

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, http-live-streaming, fairplay

I'm working with HLS FairPlay but can't correctly delete a protected downloaded content and re-download it in the same session (= without first closing the app).

step 1:
movpkg is deleted from FileManager
its content key is deleted from the .keys folder

step 2:
trying to re-download, without killing the app first, doesn't fire any delegate method from the ContentKeyDelegate flow.

Apparently, there's some sorta of caching after you do the first time:

[`processContentKeyRequest(withIdentifier: identifier, initializationData: nil, options: nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcontentkeysession/2799180-processcontentkeyrequest)

AVContentKeySession is initialized at app start.

calling `processContentKeyRequest(withIdentifier: identifier, initializationData: nil, options: nil)` the second time does nothing.

If I re-download after restarting the app(and after deleting the content) works fine.
I also tried using [invalidatePersistableContentKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcontentkeysession/3089138-invalidatepersistablecontentkey) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating new instance of the AVContentKeySession. I found this in Apple's HLS Catalog example:

```
/// Reset content key manager. May have to do this to re-download an already downloaded item. Does not reset any other keys.
func reset() {
    contentKeySession = AVContentKeySession(keySystem: .fairPlayStreaming)
    contentKeySession.setDelegate(contentKeyDelegate, queue: contentKeyDelegateQueue)
}
```